# How to get the webpack version at build time

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-5

During the execution of the webpack build I would like to get the webpack version. I need this info to make build preparations based on webpack 4 or webpack 5.

Intention: to prepare the project for an upgrade from webpack 4 to 5 I am not allowed to make this specific step myself. At some point the company build runner updates webpack.

I know that webpack has a command for it: `npx webpack --version`. How to access the version from within the build config?

Answer (score 1):

To access the webpack version from within the build config it is possible to load webpack as a dependency and check its version property:

```
const { version } = require('webpack');
```